# Question about air sealing soffit/eave area for bugs and temperature

Tags: insulation, attic, ventilation, construction, pest-control

I have a 2006 house, which is not a great vintage, but generally very solid. In the [rumpus room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpkU9.jpg) above my garage, there are [two knee-wall closets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCRs3.jpg). Despite having ample [fiberglass insulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w69O.jpg), these closets are a major source of outside air/temperature. Also, bugs (namely "ladybugs" and occasionally wasps) make their way in through [this area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s675I.jpg). Since it's now winter, and I'm not afraid of a stirring up a wasp nest, I finally lifted up the fiberglass insulation to find a 1/4" or so gap between the roofing and fascia.

- Could anyone tell me to what extent I need to "air seal" this gap? Is there supposed to be ventilation? I don't want to seal up this soffit area if was intentionally built this way. But I suspect not.
- Can I safely pull out this insulation and spray foam or caulk [the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvB8M.jpg) to the outside closed? What product should I use?
- Let's say the wasps and "ladybugs" find another way around the gap that I've sealed, how should I go about sealing off this closet from the soffit/eave area? Sheathing where the fiberglass insulation meets the sill plate (not sure what that bottom 2x4 is called)? How would a professional do this job?
- Also, if I were to sheath that rafter area over the insulation, what technique would you use to cover the coax and romex?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzh37.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMD1U.jpg) is the area in question from the outside, but it is an issue across the eave. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxNZv.jpg) is a basic diagram of what I'm looking at, the red arrow being my view of the red circle being the gap at the eave.

Whole album:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsZzp.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be tempted to just stuff some backer rod in the gap you mention.

Comment: And maybe use construction adhesive to glue it in place? Not a bad idea! Thank you.

Comment: Depending how tight the fit is, perhaps.